# PNG is blank when saving fabricjs canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Im currently making an app hosted by flask.

Im trying to take a drawing a user does on my canvas and then save it for them, the code below is what is meant to save my canvas:

```
$(document).on("click", "#savepng", function(){
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

        if(!window.localStorage){alert("This function is not supported by your browser."); return;}
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL())
        var html="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='canvas image'/>";
        var newTab=window.open();
        newTab.document.write(html);
    });
```

The when I hit save a new tab is opened and no errors show but problem is the tab is blank when its mean to show my image, I did a console log on the toDataRrl value and its just a blank png even though I drew on the canvas every time ive tested it. Heres my code for creating a simple canvas to draw on:

```
<canvas id="sheet" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <button id="savepng">Save as PNG</button>

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet', { isDrawingMode: true });

    window.onload=function(){
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet');
        canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#ff0000";
    }
```

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tkubdxz/),its working.

Comment: Same results png appears blank

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "#savepng", function() {
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    var newTab = window.open();
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        newTab.document.body.append(img);
    }
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'image/png'
    });
});
```

You can make an image() element and onload event you append that image element to body. Here is [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/1tkubdxz/2/).